Is there anyway to differentiate re-installation and update of a Mac App Store app?
I am developing an electron app and publishing to Mac App Store.
My primary goal is to clear the user data created by the app when the app is uninstalled (and re-install), but not when updated. But this is not possible on MacOS since uninstallation on MacOS is just dragging the app folder to Trash which have no way to intervene.
So I turn to try deleting user data when the app first start from a fresh install, but I found no way to differentiate an uninstall (re-install) and an update. I tried to detect fresh install by remembering and comparing at the app bundle folder last modified date, but both processes involve replacing the app bundle folder, leaving no clue to determine whether it is a fresh install or an update.
Is there anyway I can clear user data upon a re-installation but keep user data when update the app?

Why would you even want to delete the user's data? If this is truly user data, then this is nothing your application should manage. Isn't "uninstall and install again" a (somewhat) valid method to try to fix a problem with the app? I certainly wouldn't expect my data to be gone if I'd tried that.

@AlexanderLeithner "user data" here means everything stored in the ~/Library/Application Support/<my app name> directory. It is the primary location for an app to store any persistence data, which can be for the app internal use, not necessarily something the user generated or care about. I agree the expectation of data not being gone on uninstall, but it is equally valid for someone to expect data gone after uninstall. "I uninstall the app, why its stuff are still there".  Especially nowadays mobile platforms do/can do just that while Mac cannot, creating inconsistent UX.

When it comes to app store style sandboxed app, all iOS, Android, Windows wipe the whole sandbox container when the app get uninstalled while providing other means for persisting data outside the app lifecycle. Only macOS keeps the container on uninstall.
